# NSOpenPanel returns with nil values for url and urls

Tags: swift, macos, swift5, nsopenpanel

I am opening a modal panel to select a file, but in the return I am finding that the values for .url is `nil` and .urls is `[0] = {}`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var selectedFilePath: NSPathControl!

@IBAction func chooseFile(_ sender: NSButton) {
    var selectedFileURL: URL?
    let panel = NSOpenPanel()
    // configure the panel
    panel.canChooseFiles = true
    panel.canChooseDirectories = false
    panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    panel.allowedFileTypes = ["mov","mp4"]
    // open the panel
    if panel.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK {
        selectedFileURL = panel.url
        selectedFilePath.url = selectedFileURL
        ...
    }

}
```

So all subsequent function calls that pass `selectedFileURL` are receiving `nil`. However, to confound matters further, despite `panel.url` and subsequently `selectedFileURL` being set to `nil`, in the UI the `selectedFilePath` NSPathControl does update to reflect the selected file path!

I've tried many different ways of opening and responding to the panel, but in all cases I cannot access the url…

Answer (score 0):

In new projects the application is sandboxed by default.

In *Signing & Capabilities* of the target either delete `App Sandbox` (click on the little `x` on the right side) or in the section *File Access* enable `Read Only` or `Read/Write` of type *User Selected File*

Comment: I forgot to mention, I already checked that and have User Selected File set to Read/Write access. It does seem like it might be a sandbox issue, but couldn't see any additional switches to flip.